# Algorithm to find for each vertex, a vetrex that it can reach with the lowest cost in a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal

We have a **directed** graph $G=(V,E)$ and each vertex $v\in V$ has a cost: $price(v)$. Our mission is to find an algorithm that runs in time **$\mathcal{O}(|E|+|V|)$** that finds $\forall v\in V$ the minimal price of all vertices $w$ which are reachable from $v$ (all vertives $w$ s.t. there is a path from $v$ to $w$). Note that $v$ can reach itself.

As an example if the graph simply was $3\to 5 \to 1$ then the minimal price of all vertices was $1$, since all vertices can reach $1$ and its minimal.

I tried using a BFS-like algorithm but failed.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. My spelling checker misses the typo in the title, but flags one in the body of your post. * it's minimal* sadly is out of its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) $C$ of $G$ and notice that the sought value associated with all vertices $v$ in $C$ is the same. Let's call this value $P(C)$.

Compute all strongly connected components of $G$ (there are several ways to do this in time $O(|V|+|E|)$, see for example [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)) and let these be $C_1, \dots, C_k$.

Now consider a directed graph $G'=(V', E')$ whose vertex set is $V' = \{ C_1, \dots, C_k\}$ and such that there is a directed edge $(C_i, C_j)$ in $E'$ if and only if $i \neq j$ and $(u,v) \in E$ for some vertex $u$ in $C_i$ and some vertex $v \in C_j$.  Notice that $G'$ is a directed acyclic graph, and therefore admits a [topological ordering.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Compute such an ordering and assume w.l.o.g. that it is $\langle C_1, \dots, C_k \rangle$ (otherwise we can just rename the components).
This can be done in time $O(|V'|+|E'|) = O(|V|+|E|)$ (actually, Tarjan's algorithm already returns the strongly connected components in reverse topological order).

Notice that if some $C_i$ is a sink in $G'$ (i.e., it has no outgoing edges) then $P(C_i)$ can be immediately computed as  $\min_{w \in {C_i}} \text{price}(w)$

If $C_i$ is not a sink, then we have:
$$
P(C_i) = \min \big\{ \min_{w \in C_i} \text{price}(w), \min_{(C_i, C_j) \in E'} P(C_j) \big\}.
$$

By examining the vertices of $G'$ in reverse topological order, we are able to compute all values $P(\cdot)$. Moreover, notice that the time needed to compute $P(C_i)$ is proportional to the number $|C_i|$ of vertices in $C_i$, plus the out-degree $\delta_i$ of $C_i$ in $G'$. Therefore, the overall time complexity of computing $P(\cdot)$ once the topological order is known is upper bounded (up to multiplicative constants) by:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k ( |C_i| + \delta_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^k  |C_i| + \sum_{i=1}^k  \delta_i  = |V| + |E'| \le |V| + |E|.
$$

Comment: when you say a connected component, you mean a set of all vertices where $\forall v,w$ v can be reached from w or w can be reached from v? Or do you mean the set where both v can be reached from w *and* w from v? Because if it is the second case then the algorithm doesn't seem to be correct. (note: the graph is directed)

Comment: and if it is the first case, then for each component finding the minimal price doesn't sound like a trivial task (the 2nd case is incorrect because the minimal value can come outside the *strong* connected component)

Comment: I missed the fact that the graph was directed. I have now edited my answer.